# Uncaught TypeError: fieldRef.focus is not a function error in React-hook-form setFocus with Reactstrap Input

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, reactstrap

I'm using react-hook-form to manage my form. I want my interface to scroll to the first error field on error submit but I'm getting this error every single time I use `setFocus`
[image]

This is my controller code

```
<Controller
    name="first_name"
    control={control}
    render={({ field: { ref, ...field } }) => (
      <Input
           {...field}
           innerRef={ref}
           type="text"
           id="first_name"
           className={classnames({
              'input-error': formState?.errors?.first_name?.message,
           })}
           autoComplete="nope"
        />
    )}
/>
```

and this is my setFocus code block

```
useEffect(() => {
    const firstError = (Object.keys(errors) as Array<keyof typeof errors>).reduce<keyof typeof errors | null>((field, a) => {
      const fieldKey = field as keyof typeof errors;
      return !!errors[fieldKey] ? fieldKey : a;
    }, null);

    console.log({ firstError });

    if (firstError) {
      setFocus(firstError);
    }
  }, [errors]);
```

I somehow managed to create a sandbox for it but it doesn't show the same error. It errors on exact same code though.
https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-voice-vqqi47?file=/src/App.js

Comment: seems the related code to the error shown is not attached ...

Comment: @KcH what code block do you have in your mind?  The `setFocus` comes from the `useForm`  hook from `react-hook-form` library

Comment: my bad so the trace in the err is from the lib itself ? may be a reproducible sample would be better for these kind :)

Comment: @KcH yeah, seems like react-hook-form has this problem in other UI library as well like MUI. I've tried all suggested solutions so far like that `innerRef` in my code but nothing seems to work. Hold on i'll try to create a sandbox.

Comment: @KcH I edited the question and included a sandbox. Have a look. It doesn't produce the same error though. But it errors on same line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ever encounter this error, this was caused by React's `Strict Mode` in dev environment. It means that this error wont occur on live environment. If you want to test your code without this error, just temporarily remove the strict mode.

Refer to this thread [here](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/9126)